# (Newbie) React Sandbox, .js and html files

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm complete newbie to react environment. Currently I learn basics from egghead begginers guide:

https://egghead.io/lessons/react-render-two-elements-side-by-side-with-react-fragments
https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/kentcdodds/beginners-guide-to-react/tree/codesandbox/02-react-create-element?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

In this course, Instructor programming everything in html file. But in codesandbox.io there is an option to create react sandbox with .js files

What's the difference in this approaches? Is this course deprecated in some parts? Is modern developing require .js files?

Comment: All (browser) JS gets included/ran through HTML in some way. Sometimes they're separate files that get loaded, sometimes they're inline scripts, etc. Sometimes for the purpose of a demo it's faster to get up and running by doing it all within the HTML, but it does the same thing. Typically for any real app you'll want to separate it into it's own file or files. This is also a required step for doing any transpiling/minifying. The sandbox is just helping you separate things and automatically including them in the ways that make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, u can create a react app in one html file, but it`s much better to practice the right filing and separate the code into different files. F.e. HMTL code in HTML files, JS in JS and so on. U got my point.